# How to bold a partial text in Acumatica report

Tags: acumatica

I was trying to format a part of my text output to bold.

[The screenshot of my rpx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXQoi.png)

You can see from this picture, I was trying to set my Inventory ID to be displayed as bold but leave the description as regular.
Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace one field with two fields!
[image: Replace Field]

After that, set up the following properties!
[image: Inventory]

for transaction description field

[image: Description]

Comment: Thank you for helping me! is there any way I do not have to split one filed to two field?

Comment: It seems to me that no, at least in practice, I have not seen this